What does 367 * m - 362 mean in LocalDate.toEpochDay()
public long toEpochDay() {
        long y = year;
        long m = month;
        long total = 0;
        total += 365 * y;
        if (y >= 0) {
            total += (y + 3) / 4 - (y + 99) / 100 + (y + 399) / 400;
        } else {
            total -= y / -4 - y / -100 + y / -400;
        }
        total += ((367 * m - 362) / 12);
        total += day - 1;
        if (m > 2) {
            total--;
            if (isLeapYear() == false) {
                total--;            }
        }
        return total - DAYS_0000_TO_1970;
     }

It's a method in class LocalDate. what does this expression mean: ((367 * m - 362) /12) ?
search online for the meaning of '((367 * m - 362) / 12)', no answer.

You should link to where you obtained this source code.

we have two problems with the number of days of a month: 1) February has 28/29 days - solution assume it has 30 and correct later, so the year has 367 days - so we have 367*m/12 days at start of month m; 2) but 7 months with 31 days are needed for that year, there must be two consecutive 31 day months, a nice alternating sequence of 30 and 31 days is not possible - the 31 pair was chosen to be July and August - to adjust the formula for that, we subtract 362 (actually adding 5 after subtracting 367 since m is not a 0-based index) -- the if (m>2) is correcting February not having 30

Combined with if (m > 2) and if (isLeapYear() == false), it's a way to get the number of days at the start of a month without a lookup table (with integer division).
Non-Leap Years
m=1 (Jan): 0 (diff: 0)
m=2 (Feb): 31 (diff: 31)
m=3 (Mar): 59 (diff: 28)
m=4 (Apr): 90 (diff: 31)
m=5 (May): 120 (diff: 30)
m=6 (Jun): 151 (diff: 31)
m=7 (Jul): 181 (diff: 30)
m=8 (Aug): 212 (diff: 31)
m=9 (Sep): 243 (diff: 31)
m=10 (Oct): 273 (diff: 30)
m=11 (Nov): 304 (diff: 31)
m=12 (Dec): 334 (diff: 30)

Leap Years
m=1 (Jan): 0 (diff: 0)
m=2 (Feb): 31 (diff: 31)
m=3 (Mar): 60 (diff: 29)
m=4 (Apr): 91 (diff: 31)
m=5 (May): 121 (diff: 30)
m=6 (Jun): 152 (diff: 31)
m=7 (Jul): 182 (diff: 30)
m=8 (Aug): 213 (diff: 31)
m=9 (Sep): 244 (diff: 31)
m=10 (Oct): 274 (diff: 30)
m=11 (Nov): 305 (diff: 31)
m=12 (Dec): 335 (diff: 30)


It's representing the number of days that have passed due to the month factor.
For example, let's say the date is in april, then, plugging in '4' for the value of m:
(367 * 4 - 362)/12 = 92.
Given that we're in april, that means the entirety of january, february, and march have passed. That was 31 + 28 + 31 days, or 90 days. The math formula almost got us that - but it overcounted by 2.
However, in the code that immediately follows, first, it checks if this year is a leap year. If not, 1 is subtracted. That's one of em (and note that if this year was a leapyear, then the number of days in jan+feb+mar had indeed been 91 and not 90). It also always runs total-- except for january, which gets us.. 90.
So why is that, specifically, the formula? Because it works. it's just 'a formula that just so happens to luck its way into it'. The reason we know, for sure, that it 'works', is that there are only 12 possible values that need to be checked: 1-12. So, do it yourself: Write for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++), run that formula, and confirm that that formula so happens to provide exactly what we need here.

"It also always runs total-- except in january". The criteria is if m > 2. So that would exempt both January and February wouldn't it?

@Gimby It would indeed not run in February either, since the extra day from leap years only matter starting in March

@Gimby I meant it in the sense of 'it only subtracts if February is to be counted'. if m == 2, then this formula should only count the total number of days in januari. d will take care of the days in februari.

@rzwitserloot I simply pointed out an inaccuracy in the answer's text which is easily fixable. That's what comments are for.

EDIT: in -> for.
